# How do I setup an access_token ?

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth, oauth2

I have a python script on a local server that needs to be given OAuth permissions to salesforce.com

According to salesforce's documentation, I need to create a new token.

> Develop -> Remote Access -> New

I do not have any items named "Remote Access" under the Develop Menu

[image]

As a work around, I have copied my session id from the cookie in my browser, but this is not a good long term solution.

```
salesforcekey = <long number copied from my session cookie>
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $salesforcekey" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" https://foobar.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/query?q=SELECT+CaseNumber+FROM+Case+WHERE+isClosed=false+AND+IsDeleted=false+AND+Priority+IN+\(\'Critical\'\)
```

How can I grant API access to my python script? I am a user, do I need to be a salesforce administrator?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be system adminstrator to set connected apps.

The remote access has been improvised to connected application.

SetUp>Apps>Connected_Apps...you need to have admin license for same

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks, it appears that I do not have Connected_Apps as an option. I will check with the administrator.